# Drop-down list indentation for expanded elements

Tags: windows, user-interface, intellij-idea, dbeaver

Is there any possibility to manage or shrink **indentation** value (in pixels somehow) of expanded elements of drop-down list in such tools, as IntelliJ IDEA and/or DBeaver DB-tool to economize space "eaten" to the left margin (marked by red arrows at the attached screenshot) of branched long tree expansion?

For DBeaver I asked as issue about for its development-team, but got aproximate answer, that *"it depends on your OS"*

[image: Indentation shrink required]

Thank you!

Comment: DBeaver issue:
https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/14764#issuecomment-984442839

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IntelliJ IDEA:

You can set a custom value for the tree indent as follows:

1. In the IDE main menu go to Help | Edit custom properties... (agree to create file if it does not exist).
2. Add ide.ui.tree.indent=[value] line there. The smallest value allowed is 0 (and -1 is default).
3. Restart IDE.

You might also want to play around with the ide.tree.painter.compact.default=true option which can be added with the same steps.